# Ajax doesn't get a success response back after file upload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I just started with Ajax and also tried to find a solution for this.

Here is the problem:

I upload a .csv to a server. This works just fine. But after the upload "success" in the ajax call won't respond. Neither does complete or error. It shows nothing. Not even an empty alert. Just nothing. I also didn't find anything in the logs.

When I click the upload button without chosing a file to upload I get a response from success...

Here is the code:

upload.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$target_dir = 'uploads/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$response[] ='';

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$target_file))
  { 
    //$response['message'] = "File was uploaded!";
    $response['message'] = csvToJson($target_file);
  }
  else
  { 
    $response['message'] = 'Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.'; 
  }

echo json_encode($response);


function csvToJson($file) 
{
    // open csv file
    if (!($fp = fopen($file, 'r'))) {
        die("Can't open file...");
    }
    
    //read csv headers
    $key = fgetcsv($fp,"1024",";");
    
    // parse csv rows into array
    $json = array();
        while ($row = fgetcsv($fp,"1024",";")) {
        $json[] = array_combine($key, $row);
    }
    
    // release file handle
    fclose($fp);
    
    // encode array to json
    return $json;
}
?>
```

upload.js

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    // Submit form data via Ajax
    $("#form").on('submit', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = new FormData($(this)[0]);  
        $.ajax({    
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(response)
            { 
                //var json = $.parseJSON(response)
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log("Error:");
                console.log(error);
           }, 
           complete: function(response){
            alert(response);
           }

        });
    });
});
```

the form in index.php

```
<form id=form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Excel" name="submit">
</form>
```

In the end I want a json back with the content of the uploaded file. But right now there is zero output if the file is uploaded.

Thanks for any advice!

EDIT for Solution:

The problem was something way different.
I had to format the output from csvToJson to UTF-8. After that I get a json as the respone.

Function for formatting to UTF-8 (got it from another post here)

```
function utf8ize($d) {
  if (is_array($d)) {
      foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
          $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
      }
  } else if (is_string ($d)) {
      return utf8_encode($d);
  }
  return $d;
}
```

Comment: sumbitting a form loads a new page - unless you specifically prevent it from doing the default - `$("#form").on('submit', function(e) { e.preventdefault(); .... and the rest of your jqueery`

Comment: already tried it with  e.preventDefault(); before. No luck with it.

Comment: Apart from not sending a submit button value, your AJAX request should be pretty much the same, as if you submitted this form directly. So you should be able to verify whether the PHP part of this works as intended first of all, by _not_ making an AJAX request, but just submitting the form normally. Does that get you the result / response you were expecting?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, or a Javascript problem?

Comment: `already tried it with e.preventDefault(); before. No luck with it` - dont' remove it, you'll have eff all luck without it - check the developer tools console and network tabs and monitor what is happening, surely the request is made

Comment: Have you tried to set content type? `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, but cannot mark it:

The problem was something way different. I had to format the output from csvToJson() in upload.php to UTF-8. After that I get a json as the respone.

Function for formatting to UTF-8 (got it from another post here)

```
function utf8ize($d) {
  if (is_array($d)) {
      foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
          $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
      }
  } else if (is_string ($d)) {
      return utf8_encode($d);
  }
  return $d;
}
```